# Is relic shield a reasonable income item for Blitzcrank?

Tags: league-of-legends

Most of the guides for supports that I've read, they always try to say that the 'Ancient Coin' has the advantage as an income item, and that it is the best income item for supports.

I somehow agree, though Spellthief item is good when at the last upgrade since the minion-killing-disable-trigger will be removed. [Please correct this if i'm wrong]

I want to know if Relic Shield will be good for BC since he's melee, and that he gets damaged a lot ( poke, from initiation, ganks ) so the hp heal will somehow be reasonable.

Barrier or MS to ally? I see some use Relic while some use Coin. I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: Ancient coin on blitz is great because of its versatility as a tool for engaging/disengaging as well as allowing him to position quickly for making grabs. Relic shield could be useful but *not* as useful as the ancient coin (which also gives mana regen). If you're concerned about being squishy, you can make it up in other items (iceborne gauntlet, frozen heart,  banshees veil, randuins omen, etc). In regards to him sustaining in lane, you really shouldn't take too much poke until you want to engage. If people are overextending to poke you then its cuddle time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd Ancient Coin is the safest pick of all the 3 support items in general. Its gold income may not be the highest but the most reliable one (you just have to stand near minions) and its active works well with every champion/composition because you can use it to engage, disengage or catch people. Of course for Blitzcrank the bonus MS is especially nice since he relies on catching opponents.

Relic shield is more of a defensive item. You get a decent amount of gold, a shield and what most people forget: **sustain**. The sustain is more important than ever before, since Dorans got nerfed in early stages. Of course relic shield is preferred by Meele champions, since you get the below-200-hp execute bonus. On Blitzcrank I'd say you should buy it if you want to go more tanky, if you're getting poked sometimes and if you are vs another All-In botlane (Leona, Alistar, Braum, Thresh sometimes). The Active and the heal are both really good but you still have to lasthit minions to get the bonus gold.

The Spellthiefs Edge... well what should I say. It's a great item but if you're not in Troll mood, don't even think about buying it on a meele character. While its active may synergize with Blitzcrank you are better off with buying more tanky or more utility.

So basically When do you want to buy which item?

**Ancient coin**

- Pretty safe all the time
- If your team is rather movementspeed based
- If you need a stronger engage/disengage
- If you like standing in a bush and gaining gold for it

**Relic shield**

- If you/your adc are getting poked a bit
- If you are against an All-In botlane
- If you want to build more tanky

**Spellthiefs Edge**

- If you are trolling
- Full AP Slow Burst Pewpew Blitzcrank I guess?
- **Seriously don't do It on BC**

So I'd say you can really buy the coin all the time and against/with every team. You can't really do anything wrong there. Maybe this is the reason why a lot of people consider it to be the best Item on Blitz. However in some situations a relic shield will do just as fine if not better.

Comment: Maybe another thing about Relic Shield is that Blitzcrank needs mana to proc barrier — where the item gives HP. So, i'll keep that facts of yours in my mind.

Comment: Good answer! I'd say it also depends on how well your ADC does with letting you last hit cannon minions. If he lets you get each one (because it's shared) - you can make more money with the relic shield than you can with the ancient coin (and you don't even have to upgrade it if you don't want to).

Comment: I would say it really more depends on the playstyle than anything else. Spellthief can be the most useful item with an aggressive play while the other are more for passive play. The rest of the build will also help decide which item will fit best.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Spellthief on Blitz? **Please no!!!** You'd have to walk to an enemy and Q-E him every 30 Seconds. Usually you won't have the chance to do so. And if you do you will also take quite a hit. Blitz is more a Passive-Aggressive supporter that is Punishing mistakes done by the enemy.

Comment: I won't argue that you don't like it but I've seen Blitz doing well with it, with proper runes, masteries and build to make it the best option of the 3. I'm just pointing out that discarding it only on your idea of what is best isn't right.